# Keeping track of debug

Tags: c#, rest, logging, asp.net-web-api2, log4net

I have a solution where the user can send a request to a WebApi2 with a flag DEBUG. If the flag is set, the WebApi2 will log debug statement (using log4net).

How do I keep track of the flag in the code? I don't like the fact that I have to pass it to every function just to decide if I should log debug statement. Is there a way to do with either with log4net or WebApi2?

Something like a session will be nice, but that contrary to the RESTful design principle. I was wondering if there is an elegant solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used ThreadContext.Stacks["Debug"].Push("True") which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want the client to control the logging level on the server? log4net would *usually* be wired up through the web.config so you can change the logging level server-side and on the fly.

That being said, would you really need that level of granularity? If there's some sort of user profile saved in the DB, that might be the place to store this.

To strictly answer your question, a more elegant solution might be using a [custom header](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-web-services/9780596809140/ch01s13.html).

Comment: Is there a way to do that in log4net? I don't think I can change logging level for a single request (execution path) without affecting the other requests out of the box.

Comment: well you can either log a Debug, Info, Warn, etc; apologies if me using the term logging level as I did previously, about the *minimum* level that's actually going to be recorded

Comment: Again. If that what you meant, then log4net does not keep track of the log level per request.